# aspx GridView forces DIV to 100%

Tags: .net, html, gridview

I have three Gridviews that I want to present side by side.  I have them in separate DIV blocks however the first DIV always displays at 100% of browser width.  What ever I do with CSS to make the others line up, this DIV pushes everything down.

The other two DIVs don't seem to have this problem, even though all three share the same CSS.

[This link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1789673.aspx/1) explains what I thought should happen with nested DIVs, but it doesn't in this case.  The browser seems to think there is content spanning the width of the page.  But what data? Or how do I disable it?

Altering every possible permutation of width, float and display for the DIVs and the GridViews makes no difference at all.

Here is the gridview code (all three gridviews are virtually identical, showing two small columns each):

```
<div id="pending_registrations">

                     <asp:GridView ID="gvuserProfiles" runat="server"
                        OnRowCommand="gvuserProfiles_RowCommand"
                        AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                        GridLines="None"
                        CssClass="grid" 
                        AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt">

                        <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Registrations">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                 ...snip...
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>


                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Type">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                   ...snip...
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>

                    </asp:GridView>

     </div>
```

The CSS is (my latest version):

```
 #pending_registrations{
       display:inline-block;
       vertical-align:top;
 }
```

and [here's a pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoYti.png) of the three DIVs with Firebug showing the width of the first DIV. As you can see, the second two DIVs show inline just fine.

Comment: It doesn't explain the problem, but a workaround was to use position absolute on all three DIVs. Can't believe I didn't think of that earlier.

Comment: I take it you've solved this problem, if not you can float the div left and it will become the width of the content inside it

Comment: post the answer here, if you have solved it yourself and mark it as solved. A useful contribution.